# Sending a base64 image from a Xamarin app do not work

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, file-upload, xamarin.android

I am trying to send an image encoded in base 64 to a server in a xamarin app.
The same code work in a console app but just don't work in my xamarin app.

Here is the code :
It's in two times. A first call to create an item. Then a second call to add an image to it.

```
string Key = "";
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    var payloadA = "<PAYLOD>";
    var test = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("<USERNAME>" + ":" + "<PASSWORD>");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(test));
    var response = client.PostAsync("<FIRST URL>", new StringContent(payloadA, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));
    response.Wait();
    if (response.Result.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Created)
    {
        var task = response.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        task.Wait();

        Response result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Response>(task.Result);
        Key = result.Key;
    }
    else
    {
        var task = response.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        task.Wait();

        string testy = task.Result;

        throw new Exception();
    }
}
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    string payloadA = "{\"attachedFiles\":[{\"filename\":\"IMG_20200502_164721.jpg\",\"customfieldId\":\"customfield_10106\",\"issueKey\":\"" + Key + "\",\"content\":\"/9j/4StWRXhp ................. \"}]}";

    var test = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("<USERNAME>" + ":" + "<PASSWORD>");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(test));
    var response = client.PostAsync("<SECOND URL>", new StringContent(payloadA, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));
    response.Wait();
    if (response.Result.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
        var task = response.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        task.Wait();


    }
    else
    {
        var task = response.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        task.Wait();

        string testy = task.Result;

        throw new Exception();
    }
}
```

I tried instead to use WebClient but it's the same.

My request work also in postman.
They just don't work on the XAMARIN APP.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: "just don't work" is not a helpful description of the problem.  Are you getting an error or exception?  What is the response code you get from the server?

Comment: And using `.Wait` vs. `await` is asking for a synchronous deadlock in your code.

Comment: I would suggest reading up about asynchronous programming in C# a bit. For eg:You want to replace this line “ var response = client.PostAsync("<FIRST URL>", new StringContent(payloadA, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));” with “ var response = await client.PostAsync("<FIRST URL>", new StringContent(payloadA, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));”. Because the way you are doing it, is returning the responseTask not the response itself.